# Как создать docstring как в модуле bisect?

Tags: python, protocol

Когда я навожу мышку на символ `bisect_left` в моём коде, я вижу следующую сигнатуру параметра `a`:

```
(function) def bisect_left(
    a: SupportsLenAndGetItem[SupportsRichComparisonT@bisect_left],
    x: SupportsRichComparisonT@bisect_left,
    lo: int = 0,
    hi: int | None = None,
    *,
    key: None = None
) -> int
```

Меня интересует подсказка типа `SupportsLenAndGetItem[SupportsRichComparisonT@bisect_left]`. Как правильно реализовать её с применением протоколов? Я пытался найти это в исходном коде модуля `bisect`, но там его нет, ведь модуль на самом деле написан на языке `c`.

Comment: Модуль [написан на питоне](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.12.2/Lib/bisect.py#L74), но аннотаций в нём нет, потому что они [берутся из typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/main/stdlib/_bisect.pyi#L10)